# MySQL insert into table selecting data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table **Product** that has a **manufacturer** field.  The manufacturer field is currently of type **VARCHAR**.

I thought it better to create a table **Manufacturer** and alter the **Product** table to include a **manufacturer_id** field which of course shall be a foreign key referencing **Manufacturer.id**

So to migrate the data I want to insert into the new **Product.manufacturer_id** field the **id** of the **Manufacturer** whose name corresponds to the current **Product.manufacturer** field.

I'm having problems migrating the data using the following query:

```
INSERT INTO Product (manufacturer_id) 
   SELECT m.id FROM Manufacturer AS m WHERE m.name =
   SELECT p.manufacturer FROM Product AS p WHERE p.manufacturer = m.name;
```

Can anyone point me to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: An answer below looks like what you're after. But if you're still struggling, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 4):

You want `update`, not `insert`:

```
update p
    set manufacturer_id = m.id
    from product p join
         manufacturer m
         on p.manufacturer = m.name;
```

The above is SQL Server syntax (not sure why I did that; the question is clearly tagged MySQL).  The correct MySQL syntax is:

```
update product p join
       manufacturer m
       on p.manufacturer = m.name
    set p.manufacturer_id = m.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and for getting me on the right track.  I couldn't get the above query to work but the following sorted things:  **UPDATE Product p INNER JOIN Manufacturer m on p.manufacturer = m.name SET p.manufacturer_id = m.id;**